# Simple C++ Card Program. Unknown Error

Tags: c++

Ok so I am new to C++ and trying to write I simple program that is a deck of cards. But I get the errors: "unresolved externals". I have a feeling it has something to do with the instantiation in the constructor. A quick look would be appreciated.

```
#include "Card.h"
#include "Deck.h"

Deck:: Deck()
{
  this -> currentCard=0;

  this -> index = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j =0; j < 13;j++)
       {
          deck[index].setVal(i);
      deck[index].setSuit (j);
          index++;
        }
    }
 }


void Deck::shuffle()
{
  //implementation
  }
Card Deck:: dealCard()
{
  //implementation
   }


int main (){}
```

my header file is:

```
#include "Card.h"

class Deck
{
public:
Deck();
void shuffle();
Card dealCard();




private:
Card deck [52];
int currentCard;
int index;
};
```

Comment: It would help if you **posted the exact error message**. I very much doubt it has anything to do with the 'instantiation in the constructor'. More likely is that you didn't compile all of your source files or you didn't link with the correct libraries. Taking a guess I would say that you have a file Card.cpp and you didn't compile and/or link with it.

Comment: You've not shown the code in `Deck.h`.  The code in the `Deck` constructor uses  `setVal()` and
`setSuit()` but you've not shown any code for either.

Comment: Not that this matter much, but you're killing yourself for a simple data model. Picture the *numbers* 0..51. Now pick one (n=22 as a sample). Take `n%4`. thats your suit (0=spades, 1=clubs, 2=diamonds, 3=hearts.). Next take `n%13`. Thats your rank (0..12, ace high or low, your choice). In other words, you can contrive both card rank *and* suit using only a positive number and two modulo ops. Your "deck" then becomes an `int deck[52];` loaded with numbers `0..51` and shuffled. Side Benefit: You can increment the deck size by multiples of 52 to add more decks to the shoe

Comment: thats really cool. Thanks WhozCraig

Comment: @user2264737 Yes it is. [See it live](http://ideone.com/tTelDB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It error means that you have **unresolved external symbols**.

Now **Symbols** can be anything from Variables, Classes, Member functions.

Why they are unresolved is because may be some part of your code (or libraries that you are using) rely on these symbols and they are not being found because you are not linking the correct library or implementing them.

Please try compiling all your source files and make sure there are no Symbols(Variables, Classes, Member Functions etc) missing.

Comment: if I just put Card deck [52]; does that create 52 instances of the class card automatically? Like I don't need to call a new constructor for each one?

Comment: Yes it does. You (almost) never call a constructor, they just get called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`Card` class seems to be undeclared. You probably want to do it in `Card.h` file. You can forward-declare it by simply typing `class Deck;`, but remember it's just a place-holder that must be resolved somewhere anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Usually 'Unresolved externals' points to the unresolved symbol:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "the symbol that wasn't resolved"

This will show you what the linker is missing.

Hope this helps, Yaron